# Can't create pods in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am following a tutorial, where a pod is created using the below command:

```
kubectl run firstPod --image={image from dockerhub repository}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "firstPod" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/default: serviceaccount "default" not found
```

The goal of command is to pull docker image from my own repository and use it to create pod. I saw already some solutions that use .yaml file (but I didn't like the answer). All I want is to run this command. I am using windows 10 and docker desktop for a kubernetes cluster (minikube etc.).

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528398/why-dont-i-have-a-default-serviceaccount-on-kubernetes - most probably you have an issue with your cluster

Comment: The most maintainable solution will be to write out the YAML files, commit them to source control, and principally use `kubectl apply -f` to install them in the cluster.  I'd recommend avoiding "imperative" commands like `kubectl run`, except for debugging tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with network-multitool. It will keep on running a webserver and have a lot of great tools.

```
kubectl run multitool --image=praqma/network-multitool --replicas=1
```

If that works, find the podname

```
kubectl get pods
```

Then you can exec into it with the name you found above

```
kubectl exec -it multitool-3822887632-pwlr1  bash
```

From inside the container/pod you can tjek that the webserver is running by

```
curl localhost
```

If the first command doesnt work, then something is wrong.
Check if the service account exists

```
kubectl get sa
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers. Now I realize, that I forget to start my local cluster minikube.

```
minikube start
```

Now it is ok to create a pod.